# NHibernate Returning a Null Value for a Mapped Property

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm maintaining an oldish app which uses NHibernate 3.3.3.4001

I have a Class called ProcedureField, which has a property called ReportCode, with a mapping that looks like this:
`Map(x => x.ReportCode);`

The database column is of the same name and is a `nullable NVARCHAR(50)`

For reasons unknown, when I retrieve a row from the table using the PK, that property is null, when the database has a value. Examples:

```
session.Get<ProcedureField>(id);
```

or

```
session.Query<ProcedureField>().First(pf => pf.Id == id);
```

All other properties are accounted for.

And here's the super weird part. I sniffed the query using SQL Server Profiler and the actual dynamic SQL which executes DOES return the `ReportCode` string. It is just not populating the property.

And for the last bit of weirdness, if I add a new property called `ReportCodey` and map that to ReportCode, it works (but I have to leave the existing property)!

```
Map(x => x.ReportCode);
Map(x => x.ReportCodey).Column("ReportCode");
```

Upgrading to NHibernate's latest version (or any) is not an option for me as it will break a raft of things in the custom framework which this application uses (damn custom frameworks!).

Anyone encountered weirdness of this nature?

Comment: What does the `ReportCode` class look like? Is there some code in the getter or setter that's overriding NH? Do you have any interceptors that might be overriding NH?

Comment: @DavidOsborne The ReportCode property is just an auto-property (both gets and sets). There are one or 2 interceptors. Upon my examination of them, I cannot see anything which would target that property and set it to null or do something funky when a new property that maps to the same column is introduced (as set out in the question). It's a weird one alright.

Comment: I've kinda fixed this. I had created a table which was also called `ReportCode`. It looks like that was causing the issue. Strange that NHibernate went weird because  a new table had the same name as an existing column in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if this is an adequate answer, but it resolved my question.

I had created a table which was also called `ReportCode`. It looks like that was causing the issue. Strange that NHibernate went weird because a new table had the same name as an existing column in another table.

I dropped the new `ReportCode` table and it went back to working again.